# How do I use Component props in actionCreators.js?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

I'm currently building an amazon clone but have run into some issues trying to update my Redux store when adding an item to the cart. When I hard-code my action like so

```
// src/redux/actionCreators.js

export const addToCart = () => ({
    type: "ADD_TO_CART",
    item: {
        id: 1,
        title: "book",
        image: "hi",
        price: 420,
        rating: 3,
    }
})
```

the item is added to my redux store. However, I would like to use the props from my Product Component for the id, title, image, price, and rating values in my action creator.

```
// src/components/Product.js

import React from 'react';
import '../Product.css';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { addToCart } from '../redux/actionCreators'

const Product = (props) => {
    return (
        <div className="product">
            <div className="product__info">
                <p>{props.title}</p>
                <p className="product__price">
                    <small>$</small>
                    <strong>{props.price}</strong>
                </p>
                <div className="product__rating">
                    {Array(props.rating)
                        .fill()
                        .map((_, i) => (
                            <p>⭐️</p>
                        ))}
                </div>
            </div>
            <img src={props.image} alt={props.title}/>
            <button onClick={ props.addToCart }>Add To Cart</button>
        </div>
    )
}

const mapStateToProps = (state) => ({ cart: state.cart.cart })

export default connect(mapStateToProps, { addToCart })(Product)
```

so that my action would look something like this

```
// src/redux/actionCreators.js

export const addToCart = (props) => ({
    type: "ADD_TO_CART",
    item: {
        id: props.id,
        title: props.title,
        image: props.image,
        price: props.price,
        rating: props.rating,
    }
})
```

however, props are undefined. Passing props directly through the action will not work, so what would be the correct way to use my Product Component's props with my action creator?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

while addToCart use function like this

```
 <button onClick={()=> props.addToCart(props) }>Add To Cart</button>
```